# How do I show the Windows photo-printing wizard?

Tags: delphi, wia

I found the VB function [`ShowPhotoPrintingWizard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630781.aspx):

```vb
CommonDialog.ShowPhotoPrintingWizard( _
  ByVal Files As VARIANT _
) As HRESULT
```

How do I call that or get equivalent functionality in Delphi? I'm using Delphi 2010.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it might be this way for a single file:

```
uses
  ComObj;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  CommDlg: OleVariant;
begin
  CommDlg := CreateOleObject('WIA.CommonDialog');
  CommDlg.ShowPhotoPrintingWizard('d:\Image.jpg');
end;
```

Or the similar for multiple files:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Files: OleVariant;
  CommDlg: OleVariant;
begin
  CommDlg := CreateOleObject('WIA.CommonDialog');
  Files := CreateOleObject('WIA.Vector');
  Files.Add('d:\Image 1.jpg');
  Files.Add('d:\Image 2.jpg');
  CommDlg.ShowPhotoPrintingWizard(Files);
end;
```

Comment: @Andreas, thanks! I originally chose the first one matching `Wizard` in the `CommonDialog` method list. Shame on me! :-)

Comment: Can the printing wizard be used if you have the images as TBitmaps?  Maybe another question?

Comment: No, the `ShowPhotoPrintingWizard` method accepts only files, not any kind of stream, so you'll have to save the `TBitmap` images to files. And yes, that should have been a separate question ;-)